# Find the radius of the front and back wheels of a tricyle to the nearest centimetre

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

The ratio of the front wheels to the back wheel of a tricycle is in the ratio 2:3. Over 360 meters the front wheels make 160 more revolutions than the back wheel. Find the radius of the front and back wheels to the nearest centimetre.

I tried this equation:
$$(2r\pi)n+160+(2r\pi)n=360$$
However, I think that this is inaccurate. How would you find the answer?

Comment: $160\cdot 3\cdot 2\pi r_1 = 36000,160\cdot 2\cdot 2\pi r_2 = 36000$

Comment: Suppose the front wheel has radius $r$ and made $n$ revolutions, then $n \cdot 2 \pi r = 360 = (n-160) \cdot 2 \pi \frac{3}{2} r$.

Comment: how would you solve for n and r?

Comment: @Julie You have two equations. Eliminate $n$ between them, then solve for $r$.

Comment: how do you do this?

Comment: @Julie From the first equation $n = \frac{360}{2\pi r}$. From the second equation $n=\frac{360}{3\pi r}+160\,$. Equate the right-hand sides of the two and solve for $r$. Or, to find $n$ first just divide the original two equations and solve $\frac{n}{n-160}=\frac{3}{2}$ for $n$, then substitute back in either equation and solve for $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_1, r_2 $ the radii of the front wheel and rear wheel resp.

1) $r_1/r_2 = 2:3$.

Front wheel:

2)$( 2πr_1)n = 360 [m]$, where $n$ is the number of revolutions of the front wheel.

Rear wheel:

3) $(2πr_2)(n - 160) = 360 [m]$.

Divide equations : 2):3)

$(r_1/r_2)(n/(n-160)) = 1$;

Using 1):

$(2/3) n = n - 160$;

$2n = 3n - 480$;

$n = 480$.

Use 2) or 3) to find  $r_1$ or $r_2$,

get the other radius  from 1).

Helps?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$\begin{cases} \frac{r_f}{r_b}=\frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{36000}{2\pi r_f}=\frac{36000}{2\pi r_b}+160. \end{cases}$$